# How do I make HttpClient use the same traceId

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, open-telemetry

I have a IHostedService and start a timer to run job

```cs
_timer = new Timer(RunAsync, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

In the RunAsync method I create a Service from DI

```cs
public async void RunAsync(object? state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        using var scope = services.CreateScope();
        var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Service>();
        await service.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

I make the request in ExecuteAsync

```cs
public class Service
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public Service(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        var res = await httpClient.GetAsync("url");
    }
}
```

opentelemetry config

```cs
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
.WithTracing(config =>{ 
config.AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
});
```

In grafana, I can see 10 traces with 1 span each. like this

[image]

How do I set these 10 requests to use one traceId,10 spans so that I can see the total time

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Grafana, but you might try to use only a single instance of `HttpClient`, instead of creating a new instance for each request. Microsoft recommends using a long-living instance or a single and re-used instance of `HttpClient` throughout the applications lifetime.
For more information see the [Microsoft Guideline for using `HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

Each `HttpClient` request is a separate span, but you can create a *parent* span that contains all 10 `HttpClient` spans. The name for the "span" concept in .NET is `Activity`.

First, you need an `ActivitySource` if you don't already have one:

```
private static ActivitySource activitySource = new("MyNamespace.MyService", "1.0.0");
```

Then, you can start an activity on each timer invocation:

```
public async void RunAsync(object? state)
{
  using var activity = activitySource.StartActivity("MyTimer");
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    using var scope = services.CreateScope();
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Service>();
    await service.ExecuteAsync();
  }
}
```

Conceptually, this is similar to creating a child DI scope.